# Lists of concrete types show up in inspector, but not lists of interfaces

Tags: c#, unity

In one of my custom C# classes in Unity, I need to expose a `List` of objects in the inspector, and they need to conform to a specific interface.

Below are two lines from my class definition. `Card` is a concrete type in my game, and `CellObserver` is an interface. Multiple classes may implement this interface, so I'd like to define it this way if possible.

```
public List<Card> currentCards;
public List<CellObserver> observers;
```

The list of `Card` objects shows up in the inspector just fine, but lists based on `CellObserver` don't. It's not unique to this interface either - I also have one on another class that behaves the same way.

The code builds just fine, and as far as I can tell, this is valid in C#. Is there something else I need to do in Unity to implement this list? Or is this simply not an option in Unity?

Comment: If your classes don't inherit from monobehaviour you can place [System.Serializable] above the class declaration line "public class Card {}" and that will show you basic variable types in the inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably have to look into [PropertyDrawer](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html)s to get what you want. These are custom property drawers for Unity. The Unity inspector doesn't know how to render a lot of things by default (and some things it's not very good at rendering, like arrays).

With a custom property drawer you can tell the Unity Inspector how to display your interfaces. Property drawers also allow you to change the way other types are displayed.

Comment: I created a [course for Unity](http://www.lynda.com/Unity-3D-tutorials/Advanced-Unity-3D-Game-Programming/160270-2.html?utm_medium=ldc-partner&utm_source=SSPRC&utm_content=524&utm_campaign=CD15496&bid=524&subID1=wf&aid=CD15496) that covers these property drawers, it's a paid course, but you can use this [10-day free trial](http://www.lynda.com/promo/trial/Default.aspx?lpk35=7840&utm_medium=ldc-partner&utm_source=SSPRC&utm_content=655&utm_campaign=CD15496&bid=655&subID1=wf&aid=CD15496) to view those videos and download the course material.